# How to copy directories with attributes using Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

`C:\Alice\Example\` has its read-only attriube set.

`C:\Bob\Example\` is not read-only, but hidden.

When I copy and paste the `Example` directory from `C:\Alice` to `C:\Bob` using the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, the target directory `C:\Bob\Example\` remains hidden, without becoming read-only.

This is a problem, because:

- The directory icon is lost (`desktop.ini` doesn't work without the parent's read-only attribute).
- The directory becomes hidden.

Optional questions:

- Is it a bug in Windows Explorer? How to report it?

Comment: Timestamps don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot use Windows Explorer, or keyboard shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

You can use the command line tool `xcopy`, with the `/H` and `/K` parameters. This will copy hidden and read-only files, as well as copy file attributes.

> /H Copies hidden and system files also.
>
> /K Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.

Additional command line switches can be found from the command line by typing `xcopy /?`

Sample command for your situation

```
xcopy "C:\Alice" "C:\Bob" /E /H /K
```